# how to get results based on column's result type from 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, database

i have a table called users contained

```
(Table A) 
Users
user_id
username
user_type[1,2]

(Table B)     if user_type=1       
user_id
full_name

(Table C)     if user_type=2        
user_id 
full_name
```

i want to get single record set by executing single query, is that possible in PHP mysql.

Comment: Why are you asking [a question twice when it is closed as not a real question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328564/how-to-get-results-based-on-columns-result-type-from-2-tables)

Comment: This question is a bit clearer than the last one

Comment: In the future, just update your original question. I'm not closing this with a binding moderator vote (though the community is free to close) because the answers you received indicate that sense can be made out of the question. Try to be clearer initially in the future, and avoid question repetition. Finally, it would help if you edit the end of your question to better illustrate the results you're trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table_a.*, COALESCE(table_b.full_name,table_c.full_name) AS full_name
FROM table_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_b.user_id = table_a.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c ON table_c.user_id = table_a.user_id WHERE 1;
```

It uses the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which means that it joins it to `table_b` on the given condition. However, for each row in `table_a`, whether it finds a matching row in `table_b` or not, it will return the `table_a` row. If it does not find a matching row, the `table_b` columns are just NULL. Same thing with `table_c`.

Then, we just select all the `table_a` columns. However, we now have two `full_name` columns, one from `table_b` and one from `table_c`. We use `COALESCE` to merge them.

`COALESCE` returns the first non-`NULL` value.

Since we know that there is either a matching row in `table_b` or a matching row in `table_c`, it is not a problem. However, it would be a problem if somehow you allows a matching row to be found in both `table_b` and `table_c`.

The risk can be mitigated by adding additional `ON` clause conditions to get:

```
SELECT table_a.*, COALESCE(table_b.full_name,table_c.full_name) AS full_name
FROM table_a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b
             ON table_b.user_id = table_a.user_id AND table_a.user_type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c
             ON table_c.user_id = table_a.user_id AND table_a.user_type = 2
WHERE 1;
```

Still, you will need to make sure only 1 row is present for each user in `table_b` and `table_c`.

---

Instead of `COALESCE` you can optionally use `CASE` like:

```
SELECT table_a.*, CASE user_type WHEN 1
        THEN table_b.full_name
        ELSE table_c.full_name END AS full_name
...
```

or use an `IF` function like:
    SELECT table_a.*, IF(user_type=1,table_b.full_name,table_c.full_name) AS full_name
    ...

Comment: but where is user_type i want to check against user_type if user_type=1 then from table_a otherwise from table_b

Comment: You cannot do conditional joins. That is why you join with both tables, then use `coalesce` to pick the column which is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can `UNION` both tables and later on `JOIN` it with `tableA`

```
SELECT  a.User_ID,
        a.`username`,
        b.full_name,
        a.user_type
FROM    tableA a
    (
        SELECT user_ID, full_name
        FROM tableB
        UNION
        SELECT user_ID, full_name
        FROM tableC
    ) b ON a.User_ID = b.User_ID
-- WHERE a.user_type = 1            -- add extra condition here
```